# how to show or hide div or img using cordova connection plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a visual indication of the internet connection using cordova connection plugin.
if connection is off show red bullet if on show green.
any thoughts out there?

Comment: Are you using a webview or a custom widget to render a div?

Comment: show what you have done here.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the state several times you can set an interval on your JavaScript to make a call to the plugin every fixed time.

```
setInterval(function(){ callConnectionPlugin(); }, REFRESH_TIME);
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge this is a good idea but unfortunately i've tried to put document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false); inside callConnectionPlugin() is just doesn't work.

Comment: just the alerts didn't work but now is working fine here's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin you can listen for offline event as shown :

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

in your callbackfunction display the bullet by changing the css property.

Comment: thanks this worked fine when testing with alert I just need to change the alert to switch the divs or images. I've tried to put the code inside an interval function does not work as suggested by Jorge Morales below.

Comment: @user1562805  Accept the correct answer once you verify.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me as I wanted a visual representation of the connection for my app. so when the connection is on shows a small green bullet when off a small red bullet. Here's the code using cordova connection plugin.

```
    function checkConnection() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", offlineState, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", onlineState, false);
    }
    setTimeout("checkConnection()",1000);
```

the callbacks functions are :

```
    function offlineState(){
    $('.conn').addClass('offline').removeClass('online');
    }
    function onlineState(){
    $('.conn').addClass('online').removeClass('offline');
    }
```

of course after the device ready.Hope this will help someone ...although it is simple.

All the credits to kumar and jorge